# How to scale down a range of numbers with a known min and unknown max value

Tags: math, computer-science, normalization

i have a series of experiments, where the outcome of each single experiment is an integer with a known minimum value (which would be the best case) and **unknown** maximum value. These values are different for every experiment.

Is there a way to normalize such experiments to (as example) [0,1] or any other interval?

The outcome of the experiments is a set of integer c1,c2,...,cn like this:

```
f(g1)=c1 with 2 <= g1_min <= c1 <= inf
f(g2)=c2 with 2 <= g2_min <= c2 <= inf,

...

f(gn)=cn with 2 <= gn_min <= cn <= inf.
```

Im looking for a way to visualize the outcome of the experiment and to display how much each cn differs from the respective (optimal) gn_min.

Do you have any idea how to do this?

Greetings :-)

Comment: To normalize them you need, by definition, a known maximum (which might come from your experiments or by physical/mathematical laws)

Comment: Yes, with a known maximum it is easy. But for this experiment, the maximum is not known. It could be infinity in theory. Thats the point of the question.

Comment: Then simply you CAN'T **normalize** them with an unknown maximum. To what do you set 1 equal to? I don't know your domain but a theoretical maximum may be calculated. Imagine you're doing something with human beings height. In _theory_ you don't know the maximum height of your population but, in practice, physical forces/measures (gravity, blood, strength of our bones/joints, heart power to pump blood against gravity) set the maximum more or less between 4/6 meters. If upper limit is really infinity then just don't normalize, or better...ask yoursefl what do you need normalization for.

Comment: The experiments analyze the schedule length of a large number of directed graphs using different scheduling algorithms. In theory, a very very bad scheduling algorithm could identify the worst schedule length possible. The idea is to display the scheduling quality for each scheduling algorithm.

Comment: Are you analyzing on the fly or are you analyzing a result set after the fact? If it is on the fly then you could normalize as you go - your graph (or whatever) will rescale when a new highest number comes in. If you are doing it all after the fact then you can just find the max in your recordset and normalize as you feel like. Or have I missed something that means this wouldn't work?

Comment: Can't you calculate the worst case (worst possible scheduling, maximum length) before starting the experiments (knowing all the graphs)? It's not an optimal maximum but it may work. Also note that to _display_ them (or to calculate quality) you may not need normalisation before you start (think about a spreadsheet: axis updates on-the-fly). Which kind of "display" are you thinking of?

Comment: I will add an example: Lets consider graph1. c1_min=4, alg1 provides c1alg1=5, alg2 provides c1alg2=7, alg3 provides c1alg3=9. I want to show that alg1 got the best result, that differs by only 1 from the best possible value(c1_min=4). The problem here is that the maximum value could be infinity in theory, because you could always find a worse schedule if you really want. Additionally, the worst algorithms are heuristic ones, which do not provide reproduceable results. Because of that, i can not use their results as maximum value.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti what can't be done?

Comment: @AbdulAhad practically many things! For an unknown maximum you may set 1 = ∞ but then you have a _practical_ problem: all your results will be concentrated in a ridiculously small range, almost indistinguishable from each other, with a terrible **precision** (because well...in real world we often use floating point numbers with a finite precision) and to display it's even worse than the _pure_ unnormalised numbers...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I guess you're right, I'm still busy calculating the digits of pi

Comment: @AbdulAhad it's trivial, send me a message when you finished! LOL ;)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti yeah, it's taking longer than I expected.  The whole thing is based on a 2048 bit encryption algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could play around with something like:

```
(1.0 / (x - min + 1.0))
```

You can take the logarithm of the denominator if you want that kind of scale.  The result approaches 1 for infinity.  Basic calculus.

```
1.0 / (log10(x - min + 1) + 1.0);
```

Comment: It has to be the other way around. I thought about 1/(x-min+1). But this functions decreases way too fast for my needs.

Comment: @user1679928 take the logarithm of the denominator, I'll add the code

Comment: Thank you very much. I just remove "1-" and im good. Because x-min=0 is the best case, which should be displayed as 1! ;)

Comment: @user1679928 is this to DISPLAY numbers? 1 = ∞ but then you have a practical problem: all your results will be concentrated in a ridiculously small range (well unless some of them really goes to infinity), almost indistinguishable from each other, with a terrible precision (because well...in real world we often use floating point numbers with a finite precision) and to display it's even worse than the pure unnormalised numbers. This is (IMO) not a math problem but a PRESENTATION problem.

Comment: @user1679928 ok, I removed "1-"

Comment: It should be displayed like this: 0->1,....inf->0. All large numbers will be presented in a very small range above 0, which is fine in this case. All interesting numbers (for a range between 0 to 10 or 15) will be distinguishable. I know its a presentation problem. Sorry for the wrong tag

Comment: @user1679928 no problem for the tag, if this fits your requirement then even better!